# Blue Prism Applicatoion Modeller Wizard sharing

Tags: blueprism

I have a new object in BP where I would like to include the application model from another object, but how do I share it from the "old" object?

In the Application Modeller Wizard there is a choice to Share the app. model from another object (see pic.) but I can not find the place in the parent object to enable sharing.

[image]

And yes, I know, I could just add a new page in the parent object, but I would like to keep it separated if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to use the application model between objects, then you need to share it first.

1. Go to object, that has application model that you want to share
2. Double click on "Information box" on initialise page
3. On the sheet Information sheet you can see a checkbox called shareable
4. Tick it and save the object
5. You should now be able to access that model from different object

[image]

Comment: Was just what I was looking for.

Thanks a lot :)

kind regards
Per